# selected check boxes count and passing it to another activity

Tags: android, checkbox, arraylist

i have 4 check boxes in 1st activity and i wanna store only those user selected check boxes and have to show  in another activity  my question is how can i count the user selected checkboxes. please help with me logic

```
int x = 0;

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked() == true) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i != 4) {
            x = i + 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

On Submit Button

```
    if(x!=0) {
      show alert();
      and passing check boxes selected count 
}
```

Comment: value of x always 4 in selected condition.  Please explain your login

Comment: Why do you only want to submit the number of checkboxes that are checked and not which checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put checkboxes in an array:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkList = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

you can do it with:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
{
   checkList.add(YOURCHECKBOX) ;
}
```

than you can check which CB are checked (implement where you want it to save only those which are checked..) with:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<checkList.size(); i++)
{
    if(checkList.get(i).isChecked() == true)
      {
        YOURCODE
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a loop and find the number of `CheckBox` views and then accordingly get the count of checked CheckBoxes

Ex:

```
main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    count = 0;
                    int childcount = main.getChildCount();
                    for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                          View view = main.getChildAt(i);
                          if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
                              if(((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
                                  count++;
                          }
                    }
                    text.setText("count: " + count);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Doesn't matter how many checkboxes you have in XML. The result for `count` will be the number of "checked" checkboxes